# Trouble fetching nodes

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm new to XML/Nokogiri. I'm trying to fetch all the nodes with a certain name from an XML document someone else generated. The document looks like:

```
<taxonomy>
  <taxonomy_name>World</taxonomy_name>
  <node atlas_node_id = "val">
    <node_name></node_name>
    <node atlas_node_id = "val>
      <node_name></node_name>
       <node atlas_node_id = "val">
         <node_name></node_name>
       </node>
       <node atlas_node_id = "val">
          <node_name></node_name>
       </node>
    </node>
    <node atlas_node_id = "val">
      <node_name></node_name>
    </node>
    <node atlas_node_id = "val">
      <node_name></node_name>
    </node>
  </node>
</taxonomy>
```

I want to pull ALL the nodes with the attribute `atlas_node_id`. In my `build_files` method I have the following line:

```
destinations = tax_file.xpath("//node")
```

where `tax_file` is previously set to point to the XML file.

The above returns what seems like ALL the nodes in the file and if I try to set `destinations` to `tax_file.xpath("//node_name/node")` then I get an empty NodeSet. Is there some way I can pull all the nodes with the attribute `atlas_node_id`?

I glanced through "[Searching a XML/HTML Document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)" but didn't really see anything that could help. Am I missing something really obvious?

**Update**

After trying the solutions suggested by haradwaith and Alexey Shein - both solutions seem to fetch all the nodes as one large node? Testing in irb:

```
destinations = tax_file.xpath("//node[@atlas_node_id]") (OR)
destinations = tax_file.css('[atlas_node_id]')
d = destinations[0]
d.content
>> \n      Africa\n      \n        South Africa\n        \n          Cape Town\n          \n            Table Mountain National Park\n          \n        \n        \n          Free State\n          \n            Bloemfontein\n          \n        \n        \n          Gauteng\n          \n            Johannesburg\n          \n          \n            Pretoria\n          \n        \n        \n          KwaZulu-Natal\n          \n            Durban\n          \n          \n            Pietermaritzburg\n          \n        \n        \n          Mpumalanga\n          \n            Kruger National Park\n          \n        \n        \n          The Drakensberg\n          \n            Royal Natal National Park\n          \n        \n        \n          The Garden Route\n          \n            Oudtshoorn\n          \n          \n            Tsitsikamma Coastal National Park\n          \n        \n      \n\nSudan\n\nEastern Sudan\n\nPort Sudan\n\n\n\nKhartoum\n\n\n\nSwaziland\n\n
```

Where I would have expected to see just 'Africa'. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: A [quick search](https://www.google.com/search#q=atlas_node_id) shows that there is a gem to help process that document. Have you tried it? What happened? The documentation says the author used a SAX processor, which Nokogiri has, and which can help unravel this sort of XML. Trying to do it using Nokogiri's DOM mode will be awkward so I'd recommend following the path of least resistance and use the gem.

Comment: @theTinMan The exercise is to test/expand my XML knowledge so I'd prefer to do this 'manually' if possible. Thanks for the suggestion though, I'll keep using other gems in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `[]` CSS selector:

```
xml = <<EOD
<taxonomy>
  <taxonomy_name>World</taxonomy_name>
  <node atlas_node_id = "val">
    <node_name>Africa</node_name>
    <node atlas_node_id = "val>
      <node_name>Capetown</node_name>
    </node>
  </node>
</taxonomy>
EOD

tax_file = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
nodes = tax_file.css('[atlas_node_id] > node_name')
p nodes.first.text # => "Africa"
```

You can read short introduction to CSS selectors on [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors).

Oh, it seems you didn't need the nodes with attribute `atlas_node_id` themselves, but their `<node_name>` children.

What code above is actually says is `find all tags that have an attribute with name "atlas_node_id" and get all his immediate (i.e. 1 level deep) children with tag "node_name"`.

Comment: Please explain why this will help. Tossing out code is like handing a fish to someone who is starving. Explaining how it works is like teaching them how to fish, and is how we're supposed to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for taking so long to get back to you, I had computer trouble. Unfortunately, I'm still not getting the required results. I've updated my answer to show what happens when I run your code.

Comment: Ah, my bad for not explaining properly! This helps a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find an explanation of the [XPath 1.0 syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) in the documentation.

To get all the nodes with an attribute `atlas_node_id`, you can do:

```
tax_file.xpath("//node[@atlas_node_id]")
```

Comment: Please, don't suggest content on w3schools, it's either wrong on inconsistent, see http://www.w3fools.com/ for details on this topic.

Comment: I've replace w3schools by a more relevant documentation

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and I apologise for taking so long to get back to you, I had some computer trouble :) I've updated my answer with what happens when I run your suggested code. Unfortunately the results aren't what I'm looking for.